# Conjugate prior bayesian inference on multivariate GMM

Tags: bayesian, posterior, gaussian-mixture-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, conjugate-prior

I am trying to understand how the posterior looks like when running Bayesian inference on a multivariate Gaussian-mixture model.

$p(\mathbf{x}) \propto \sum_{i=1}^M w_iN(\mathbf{x}|\mu_i,\Sigma_i)$.

Considering having a conjugate prior ($P_0$) on the form of a Dirichlet times a product of Normal-Inverse-Wishart (Following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_continuous_distribution) for the conjugate prior of the multivariate Gaussian). Then the parameters updates after adding one single sample, looks like this:

$P(\theta|\mathbf{x}) \propto P_0(\theta)P(\mathbf{x}|\theta) = Dir(\mathbf{w}|\mathbf{a})\prod_{i=1}^M\mathcal{NIW}(\mathbf{\mu_i},\Sigma_i|\mathbf{\mu_0}_i,\kappa_{0i},\nu_{0i},\mathbf{\Psi}_i)\sum_{j=1}^M w_j\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}|\mu_j,\Sigma_j)$
$ =\sum_{j=1}^M w_j Dir(\mathbf{w}|\mathbf{a})\prod_{i=1}^M\mathcal{NIW}(\mathbf{\mu_i},\Sigma_i|\mathbf{\mu_0}_i,\kappa_{0i},\nu_{0i},\mathbf{\Psi}_i)\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}|\mu_j,\Sigma_j)$

$=\sum_{j=1}^M w_j c_j Dir(\mathbf{w}|\mathbf{a})\mathcal{NIW}(\mathbf{\mu_j},\Sigma_j|\mathbf{\mu_0}_j^*,\kappa_{0j}^*,\nu_{0j}^*,\mathbf{\Psi}_j^*)\prod_{i\neq j}^M\mathcal{NIW}(\mathbf{\mu_i},\Sigma_i|\mathbf{\mu_0}_i,\kappa_{0i},\nu_{0i},\mathbf{\Psi}_i)$

where the $^*$ indicates the updated parameters after combining the normal distribution of that component with its prior.

So, up to this point I follow. However, in order for this to be of use I need to get the constant $c_j$ resulting from the update step. When looking at the parameter updates on e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_continuous_distribution), but also many other sources (e.g. [Bayesian data analysis - Third edition](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/)) we only get the posterior up to a proportionality. I.e. $\mathcal{NIW}(\mathbf{\mu},\Sigma|\mathbf{\mu_0},\kappa_{0},\nu_{0},\mathbf{\Psi})\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}|\mu,\Sigma) \propto \mathcal{NIW}(\mathbf{\mu},\Sigma|\mathbf{\mu_0}^*,\kappa_{0}^*,\nu_{0}^*,\mathbf{\Psi}^*)$. In this case however we need the constant in order to ensure that the relative weighting will be correct. Does anyone have a source for this? And an expression?

Comment: Could add that I am trying to follow the proposed method in https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05881, especially section 4.2, but the details are not really given.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this has a closed form solution. That would be the obvious reason why sources only give the solution up to a constant. I guess you could get samples for some examples to get an intuition...